# Jenkins CLI - create and update views

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-cli

I'm not sure how to properly use the Jenkins CLI to create and update views.

For example, I am exporting a view in this way:

```
java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s http://jenkins.com/ get-view "TEST" --username $username --password $password >> $WORKSPACE/test.xml
```

The xml file contains the entire tree structure along with all the Jenkins jobs.

As I try to create a new view:

```
java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s http://jenkins.com/ create-view "TEST2" < $WORKSPACE/test.xml --username $username --password $password
```

It creates a view with all the folders, but when I click on a folder it moves me to the Jenkins home page.

This is my structure:

[image]